# Vertical border messed up by horizontal border - flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I created a table using flexbox. I'm wanting to add a vertical line down the center and so I added a `border-right` to all the first columns, however the borders on the bottom of the rows are breaking up the visual flow of the vertical line. I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around how to solve this. **How can I add a vertical line while still keeping the bottom border?**

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/oczxqxmu/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove

```
.flex_row:not(:last-child) {
        border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
}
```

Like this 
https://jsfiddle.net/oczxqxmu/1/

If you want to keep the bottom-borders, use ::after and position:absolute to create a line in the middle of your table, like this

https://jsfiddle.net/oczxqxmu/11/